# Jquery onclick function not working in mustache template

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my mustache template:

```
<script id="test1" type="html">
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="1">
        {{#list}}
        <li><a href="" class="Teamname"  data-url="/getteam?teamID={{teamID}}"> {{teamName}} </a></li>
        {{/list}}
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is my mustache HTML target:

```
<div id="my1"></div>
<script type="text/html" id="s2">
  <h1>this is heading</h1>
  {{#list}}
  <p>{{teamName}}</p> 
  {{/list}}
</script>
```

This is my mustache AJAX call, which is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function() {
    var u = $(this).data("url");
    alert(apiURL + u);
    console.log("url", u);

    $.ajax({
      url: apiURL + u,
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(response) {
        var output = $("#my1");
        var template = $("#s2").html();
        var html = Mustache.render(template, response);
        output.append(html);
      },
      error : function(err) {
        alert('Error');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: The mustache template is appended to the DOM after it loads, so you need to use a delegated event handler: `$(document).on('click', 'a', function() ...`

Comment: That's working.